# How do I print the full value of a long string in gdb?

Tags: c++, c, string, debugging, gdb

I want to print the full length of a C-string in GDB.  By default it's being abbreviated, how do I force GDB to print the whole string?

Answer (score 614, accepted):

```
set print elements 0
```

[From the GDB manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Print-Settings.html#index-number-of-array-elements-to-print):

> `set print elements` *`number-of-elements`*

> Set a limit on how many elements of an array GDB will print. If GDB is printing a large array, it stops printing after it has printed the number of elements set by the `set print elements` command. This limit also applies to the display of strings. When GDB starts, this limit is set to 200. **Setting *number-of-elements* to zero means that the printing is unlimited**.

Comment: Nowadays you might also need "set print repeats 0", otherwise GDB will omit repeated elements of the string/array.

Comment: this also applies to array types too

Comment: You may also need to "set max-value-size unlimited".

Answer (score 117):

As long as your program's in a sane state, you can also `call (void)puts(your_string)` to print it to stdout. Same principle applies to all functions available to the debugger, actually.

Comment: This answer is even better than "set print elements 0" (for my purposes) because it respects the newline/carriage return chars instead of escaping them.

Comment: Good solution, but doesn't work when trying to analyze core dump file

Comment: Note: this option only works if you are debugging a live program.  You can't use GDB's "call" command when you are debugging a core file.

Comment: also requires gdb to be sane, which increasingly seems to NOT be the case (I get "No symbol "puts" in current context." on my Mac OS X machine)

Comment: I simply wrtie "puts(your_string)" in the output window of xcode

Comment: Also doesn't work when you debugging a program which doesn't have `puts()` and problematic when `puts()` uses a UART and the UART of your target requires a running CPU.

Answer (score 59):

The `printf` command will print the complete strings:

```
(gdb) printf "%s\n", string
```

Comment: sorry but this is not true

Comment: This seems to respect the `set print elements nnn` limit, and will not print the complete string unless you do `set print elements 0`.

Comment: When I try this I only get: "Value can't be converted to integer."

Comment: for std::string you need string.c_str() in order to avoid the "Value can't be converted to integer" error

Comment: Doesn't work if you are debugging a core dump.

Answer (score 44):

There is a third option: the x command, which allows you to set a different limit for the specific command instead of changing a global setting. To print the first 300 characters of a string you can use `x/300s your_string`. The output might be a bit harder to read. For example printing a SQL query results in:

```
(gdb) x/300sb stmt.c_str()
0x9cd948:    "SELECT article.r"...
0x9cd958:    "owid FROM articl"...
..
```

Comment: I was wondering what "x/300sb" meant. With the help of this [cheat sheet (pdf)](http://refcards.com/docs/peschr/gdb/gdb-refcard-a4.pdf), I've translated "x/300sb cstr" as "eXamine 300 units (Bytes) of memory at address cstr, interpreted as a NULL-terminated string (S).". If your string has length 100, then you will see lots of garbage, because all 300 bytes are printed, whether they make sense or not. +1 nevertheless for introducing me to `x`!

Answer (score 23):

Just to complete it:

```
(gdb) p (char[10]) *($ebx)
$87 =   "asdfasdfe\n"
```

You must give a length, but may change the representation of that string:

```
(gdb) p/x (char[10]) *($ebx)
$90 =   {0x61,
  0x73,
  0x64,
  0x66,
  0x61,
  0x73,
  0x64,
  0x66,
  0x65,
  0xa}
```

This may be useful if you want to debug by their values

Answer (score 2):

Using `set elements ...` isn't always the best way. It would be useful if there were a distinct `set string-elements ...`.

So, I use these functions in my .gdbinit:

```
define pstr
  ptype $arg0._M_dataplus._M_p
  printf "[%d] = %s\n", $arg0._M_string_length, $arg0._M_dataplus._M_p
end

define pcstr
  ptype $arg0
  printf "[%d] = %s\n", strlen($arg0), $arg0
end
```

Caveats:

- The first is c++ lib dependent as it accesses members of std::string, but is easily adjusted.
- The second can only be used on a running program as it calls strlen.