# How to print a null-terminated string with newlines without showing backslash escapes in gdb?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have a variable

```
char* x = "asd\nqwe\n ... "
```

and I want to print it with newlines printed as newlines not *backslash n*.
Is it possible?

Comment: if nought else works, you can replace the '\n' with '\x0a' - this will the linefeed char directly.

Comment: @slashmais: This will still show up as `\n` in gdb output

Comment: Actually, I came here for a way to PRINT the \n >.> ..
I was able to do this: print (char*)[nsstring cString]

Comment: For those who don't care about the `\n`, use: `x/s x`

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Update:
Why not just use the gdb `printf` command?

```
(gdb) printf "%s", x
asd
qwe
...
(gdb)
```

---

Old answer:
From within the debugger you can execute commands. Just call `printf`

```
(gdb) call printf("%s", x)
asd
qwe
...
(gdb)
```

Comment: I can't use stdout or stderr because these channels are attached to other program.

Comment: Note that it's important to terminate the printf command with a /n if your char* doesn't already end with one.

Comment: Worth to note that `printf()` function call may succeed and return the number of characters in the string, but not actually output those characters on the screen; the same holds true for `puts()` function call and perhaps others of that kind. In contrast, the built-in `printf` command works as expected.

Answer (score 37):

Use the string specifier:

```
print /s x
```

Comment: This is definitely better than calling the debugged program's functions like `printf`, but may only work on relatively new versions of GDB: mine yields “Format letter "s" is meaningless in "print" command”, for example.

Comment: This don't work when `x` is a variable other than address, in that case, need use `x` command, e.g `x/s x`, or need a type convert, e.g `p (char *) &x`.

Comment: This will not work when the string is larger than some length. It gets truncated when printing. printf method does print the full string.

Comment: when your string is in a buffer then "p/s (char *)buff"

Comment: In response to @sadashiv30 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/233339/2796832 and try set print elements 0