# Print whole string verbatim in gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm printing a string(char *) in gdb

```
(gdb) p l
l=0x9aa1f48 "up2 129104596496602200 19 0 0 3 0 eth1 XX :001CB",'0' <repeats 12 times>, "DC"
```

Is there a setting to have `p` print the whole string and not fill inn the "repeats ... ". While at it - also extend the default printable length of a string, `p` seems to cut off if the string is quite long.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233328/how-do-i-print-the-full-value-of-a-long-string-in-gdb

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
set print repeats 0
```

Example:

```
(gdb) p "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
$6 = 'a' <repeats 30 times>
(gdb) set print repeats 0
(gdb) p "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
$7 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
(gdb) set print repeats 10
(gdb) p "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
$8 = 'a' <repeats 30 times>
```

Answer (score 13):

Use gdb's printf command like this:

```
(gdb) printf "%s\n", a
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

instead of

```
(gdb) p a  
$1 = 'a' <repeats 32 times>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(gdb) x /s l
```

Comment: Still get the "<repeats 12 times>" stuff.

Comment: That's odd - I get that with `p` but not with `x /s`.