# How do i get GDB to print 256 values of an array?

Tags: c, gdb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I print the full value of a long string in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233328/how-do-i-print-the-full-value-of-a-long-string-in-gdb)

I am using the command

```
(gdb) p/d *data@256
```

And this gives me the result

```
   $11 = {9591, 0, 3194, -2, -1411, 0, -3713, 1, 383, -1, 3966, -1, 3839, 0, 766, 
  -1, -641, -1, -641, -1, 509, 0, 382, 0, 1150, -1, 1790, 0, 2430, 0, 1022, 0, 
  -2304, 0, -1538, 0, 638, -1, 4093, -1, 3070, 0, -641, -1, -2946, 0, -1024, 
  0, 2687, 0, 4606, -1, 1150, 0, -1410, 0, -1665, 0, 1792, 0, 2816, -1, 1152, 
  0, 384, 1, -3, 1, 1279, 0, 128, 0, -128, 1, 640, 1, 1791, 0, 2046, 0, 383, 
  0, -1024, -1, -130, 1, 1663, -1, 2814, 0, 896, 0, -898, 0, -1153, -1, 255, 
  0, 1663, 0, 1024, 0, -129, 1, -897, 0, -384, 1, 896, 0, 896, 0, -1, 0, -129, 
  0, 127, 0, 639, 0, -128, 1, 128, 0, 0, 0, 895, -1, 639, 0, -256, 0, -129, 
  -1, 255, 0, 1023, 1, 1150, 0, 257, 0, -129, 0, 1, 0, 511, -1, 640, 0, 128, 
  1, -128, 1, -256, 0, 0, 0, 129, -1, 128, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, -1, 1, 128, -1, 
  -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 128, 0, 0, -1, -128, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, 255, -1, 127, 1, 
  -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 128, 0, 128, 1...}
```

How do I get it to show me all 256 values instead of only showing some followed by the ellipsis it is showing at the end?  The value 1 does not repeat.

Comment: Yea that answered my question. Unfortunately it doesn't have a very descriptive title.