# Limit the GDB output length

Tags: gdb

I have a structure that describes a bitmap. It looks like this

```
struct bitmap {
    int XSize;
    int YSize;
    unsigned char *pData;
};
```

When an instances of this structure is initialized pData points to thousands of random-like but non-zero bytes. When I print the instance of the structure GDB shows a lot of meaningless bytes. That very time consuming. When the `disp` of such a variable is active I get the output for each step what delays debugging.

Is there a GDB option that limits the output length?

When the bytes are meaningless I could change the type of `pData` to `void *`. But since the structure is used in a precompiled library the type can't be changed. Can the type that GDB uses for `print` and `disp` be "overridden"?

Comment: Duplicate answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233328/how-do-i-print-the-full-value-of-a-long-string-in-gdb

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `print elements 4` will limit the number of `pData` characters to 4, but it will *also* limit all other strings and arrays, which could be quite annoying (e.g. `print filename` would produce `/tmp...` when the actual value is `/tmp/foobar`.

A possibly better approach is to write a Python pretty-printer for `struct bitmap` (assuming you have sufficiently recent GDB). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12775126/50617) on how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

As Paul has pointed out the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233328/how-do-i-print-the-full-value-of-a-long-string-in-gdb) gives the correct command to allow unlimited length.

To limit the length you need the command

```
set print elements n
```

where n is the maximum number of elements. Setting n to 0 gives the unlimited length.