# How to view values of variables in KDevelop?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, kdevelop

I am using `KDevelop` as IDE for my `C++` program. I have an array `char buffer[1024]` in my program. After reading data to buffer, I would like to check it manually. But in the left panel, I need to read the array `character by character`. Is there some way by which I can get the content of the array at a stretch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use GDB tool view available in KDevelop. In KDevelop 4.6, `Window->Add ToolView->GDB` will open the `GDB` tool view at the bottom/left/right of `KDevelop IDE`. Debug your program and at the point at which you have to check value of the variable, enter `print variable_name` in the textbox corresponding to `GDB cmd`. The value of variable will be printed.

Some example commands:

Show an array (will show first 200 elements by default):

```
(gdb) print buffer
print buffer
$1 = "\000\001\002\003\004\005\006\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037 !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\177\200\201\202\203\204\205\206\207\210\211\212\213\214\215\216\217\220\221\222\223\224\225\226\227\230\231\232\233\234\235\236\237\240\241\242\243\244\245\246\247\250\251\252\253\254\255\256\257\260\261\262\263\264\265\266\267\270\271\272\273\274\275\276\277\300\301\302\303\304\305\306\307"...
```

Show an array range buffer[index]@count:

```
(gdb) print buffer[50]@40
print buffer[50]@40
$2 = "23456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY"
```

Comment: GDB tool view?? Where will I get it from?

Comment: Oops!! it prints only first 200 characters even if  i give print buffer[0]@250 :(

Comment: @Jackz I guess GDB puts that limitation, you may want to dig into GDB docs if there is any way to turn off / extend the limit. Please share if you find something interesting.

Comment: Ya.. I got it from here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233328/how-do-i-print-the-full-value-of-a-long-string-in-gdb/233339#233339

Answer (score 0):

There's the `Variables` tool view.
Show it by right clicking left, right or bottom border of KDevelop's window and click `Variables`