# Can I copy a string from the application to the clipboard in gdb/ddd?

Tags: gdb

I am debugging a C++ application in ddd.

I have a <strike>`char *` variable</strike> *null-terminated string* which is so long that ddd truncates when displaying it. I want to examine this string in an external application, so how can I copy it to the clipboard, or otherwise export it from gdb?

**EDIT**: to clarify because some commentators seem confused -- this is *not* a clipboard API question. It seems an obvious useful feature that a debugger allow one to capture and examine arbitrary strings in a debugged program's memory. So, can it be done in gdb, and how?

Comment: On what OS? That is platform specific. C has no knowledge of the clipboard

Comment: Not related to C (different language) or C++.

Comment: @Olaf Ups... Honestly I read C up there, either way... That is correct. This is not related to C++. Your OS API should provide some way to access the clipboard. Again, without that piece of info no one will be able to help you

Comment: @rlam12: It is not even about programming. Just how to use gdb

Comment: @rlam12, any platform-specific details will be handled by gdb, if such a feature exists at all.

Comment: @Olaf, yes it's about gdb. That makes it about programming. Notice that a tag exists here for gdb questions.

Comment: @spraff: not necessarily. it is about using you UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a <strike>`char *` variable</strike> *null-terminated
>   string* which is so long that ddd truncates when displaying it.

It is not ddd that truncates long string, it's gdb. By default gdb truncates all strings to 200 chars when displaying them. You can set your own limit or set it to zero to print unlimited strings like this:

```
(gdb) set print elements 0
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/233328/72178).

Comment: Thanks, although I don't want to print it, I want to export it. This string is many thousands of characters long, I don't want to handle it in gdb/ddd.

Comment: You can save it to a file (gdb.txt by default): `(gdb) set logging on`
`(gdb) print str`